# Accepted edits are not explained on the revamped user reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-graph

The new reputation tab for users allows you to see the break-down of scores you've got for a question (which I think is a very nice feature, btw, particularly for new users).

However, it seems to be missing an explanation of what has happened when the user has gained +2 from a confirmed edit.

For example:

[image: user reputation page showing the explaination for an upvote +10, but an empty gap where the explaination for a edit +2 should be.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed:

[image: user reputation page correctly showing the description of an approved edit]